# White and Blank Page Problem in ElectronJs

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm new at ElectronJs, when I tried to open `<a href="./page.html">Go to page</a>`, a new page in the same window, it has opened a blank and white page.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- All of the Node.js APIs are available in this renderer process. -->
    We are using Node.js <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chromium <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.

    <a href="./page.html">Go to page</a>

    <script>
      // You can also require other files to run in this process
      require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

First, my code was like `<a href="page.html">Go to page</a>` and then I changed my code to `<a href="./page.html">Go to page</a>`.

But this did not fix my problem, still not opening `page.html`.

I would like to make a multiple page GUI with electronJs, and I don't know how to figure out this white page problem.

[Video demonstrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvK42.jpg)

[Files of the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6WUJ.jpg)

> i checked console.log() with `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` and problem is wrong file path. When i opened my project with Electron Fiddle, it didnt took my folder path (`C:\Users\Demir\Desktop\Softwares\li_software`). Electron Fiddle opened my project from `C:\Users\Demir\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-10260KLe0XorfFNK8`. So when i move my page.html or css files to tmp-10260KLe0XorfFNK8 folder, problem solved.

Comment: at dev run or prod run? which one?

Comment: this occurs from the wrong path configuration. page.html is not in the right place. Show me your current project structure.

Comment: I suggest you acquaint yourself with devTools and `console.log()` [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/electron/electron_debugging.htm)

Comment: I added links in my post, you can check it now, i guess page.html is in right place in folder. I created a folder which name is pages and I tried href="./pages/page.html" but same result.

Comment: i will check devTools and console.log() thanks.